# How to make a superscript of arbitrary width?

Tags: superscripts, box, phantom

I'm trying to make the following two commands of the same width:

```
\newcommand{\Bsh}{\ensuremath{B^{H}_{s}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Bsl}{\ensuremath{B^{L}_{s}}\xspace}
```

in order to avoid these ugly alignment issues:

[image]

I have tried without any success to use a combination of \smash, \llap, \rlap, \clap, \phantom etc.
It seems that \smash does not work as intended in superscripts.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Would it be acceptable if the vertical bars of the kets were aligned (and the two `\rangle` wouldn't)? Or do you really want the two kets to have the same width?

Comment: I want the two character having the same width, as they enter in several equations, several times. I has a similar issue with the height of other two commands, which I solved in the following way: 
``` 
\newcommand{\Bs}{\ensuremath{B^0_s}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Bsbar}{\ensuremath{\smash{\overline{B}}\vphantom{B}^0_s}\xspace
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might do. I allocate the same left-aligned width for each of the superscripts.

**ORIGINAL Answer:**

Good if one does not need the script styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xspace,eulervm}
\newcommand{\Bsh}{\ensuremath{B^{\mathmakebox[.6em][l]{H}}_{s}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Bsl}{\ensuremath{B^{\mathmakebox[.6em][l]{L}}_{s}}\xspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \vert\Bsh\rangle &= 0\\
  \vert\Bsl\rangle &= 1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**REVISED ANSWER:**

EDITED to better handle scalable space in smaller math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xspace,eulervm,scalerel}
\newcommand{\Bsh}{\ensuremath{B^{\ThisStyle{%
  \mathmakebox[2.05\LMex][l]{H}}}_{s}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Bsl}{\ensuremath{B^{\ThisStyle{%
  \mathmakebox[2.05\LMex][l]{L}}}_{s}}\xspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\scriptscriptstyle
  \vert\Bsh\rangle~
\scriptstyle
  \vert\Bsh\rangle~
\textstyle
  \vert\Bsh\rangle &= 0\\
\scriptscriptstyle
  \vert\Bsl\rangle~
\scriptstyle
  \vert\Bsl\rangle~
\textstyle
  \vert\Bsl\rangle &= 1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @campa While my chars scale with math style, I recall that `em` does not so scale with math style...However, I will be editing to fix, but you may consider undeleting your answer...they are two different approaches, after all.

Comment: @campa I ended up doing it with my `\ThisStyle{...\LMex...}` approach of `scalerel` package, where `\LMex` is one ex that scales with the math style.  Nonetheless, it looks as it your approach already takes this into account.

Answer (score 3):

Let TeX do the box-measuring for you with the help of `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` (from [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)). Different elements/`<stuff>` with the same `<tag>` are set in a (text) box with maximum width. You can manually adjust the `<align>`ment on a per-box case, with the default being `c`entred.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox,amsmath}

\newcommand{\Bsh}{\ensuremath{B^{H}_{s}}}
\newcommand{\Bsl}{\ensuremath{B^{L}_{s}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
                 \lvert \Bsh \rangle &= x \\
                 \lvert \Bsl \rangle &= y \\
  \lvert \eqmakebox[B]{\Bsh} \rangle &= x \\
  \lvert \eqmakebox[B]{\Bsl} \rangle &= y
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

This requires two compilations with any change in the maximum width associated with any specific `<tag>`.